# Tinymce - creating a customized javascript save button

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

So I'm trying to replace 'mybutton's' fuction in the code below with another code that prompts to save the content to a file in a pop-up box. mybutton is what I want to use but change the function from inserting that text "It's my button!" to the function in the code further below.

```
<script>
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  toolbar: 'mybutton',
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.addButton('mybutton', {
      text: 'My button',
      icon: false,
      onclick: function () {
        editor.insertContent('&nbsp;<b>It\'s my button!</b>&nbsp;');
      }
    });
  },
  content_css: [
    '//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
  ]
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure the proper way to replace the mybutton function's to the function below or what to do with the document.getElement line either. Could I somehow have the mybutton work to this as separate code or does it have to be within tinymce itself? Really no idea, any advice would help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveFileAs() {
    if (promptFilename = prompt("Save as ADD EXTENSION", "")) {
        var textBlob = new Blob([document.getElementById("textarea").value], {type:'text/plain'});
        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.download = promptFilename;
        downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textBlob);
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}

document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = saveFileAs;
</script>
```

Hopefully this makes sense, let me know if anything else is needed.

EDIT:

The answer below helped but it doesn't save any NEW data entered into the textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer part of your question you can call any JavaScript that is part of the page from a function in your TinyMCE init.  The init is simply a JavaScript object and can interact with other JavaScript on the page.  Assuming the `saveFileAs()` function is loaded on the page you could do this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  toolbar: 'mybutton',
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.addButton('mybutton', {
      text: 'My button',
      icon: false,
      onclick: function (editor) {
        saveFileAs(editor);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

What are you trying to do in the `saveFileAs()` method?

Comment: Thanks that works but now I can't seem to get it to send current content of the textarea, only what was originally there...

Comment: TinyMCE does not automatically update the `<textarea>` as you type.  You can use `tinymce.triggerSave()`which will force TinyMCE to update the `<textarea>` before you grab the content.  Alternatively you can just use TinyMCE's APIs to get the content from the editor ... if you pass the editor instance to your function as I did in the example code you would them do something like `editor.getContent()` to get the current HTML from TinyMCE.

Comment: I'm still a bit new to this, how would I implement either into the button? Just not sure where I should add them in the code.

Comment: The simplest way is just to put `tinymce.triggerSave();` as the first line in your `saveFileAs()` function.  If you can't get it working can you please create a TinyMCE Fiddle so people can see the entire code?  At this point you have the APIs you need - you just have to put them in the right places.

Comment: Oh sweet that worked! Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: In the latest version, add button method is inside the  editor.ui.registry 
 => `editor.ui.registry.addButton('myCustomToolbarButton',`